# Firefox is not rendering CSS background (Firefox error/bug?)

Tags: css, firefox

After spending a while creating an online portfolio, then uploading it, I noticed an issue with one of my sections. On the "Advertisement" section, I noticed it was not displaying the information, just the title. So, I kept on re-pushing the stylesheet.css, even editing it, and it would still look the same. The HTML, CSS, and JS is working how I wrote it. But it is just the section that is not showing. After browsing online and on stackoverflow for an answer, I believe it has to do with Firefox. When using Firebug, I noticed the section's background has been removed, causing the entire section to "disappear." It works just fine on Chrome. I'm not worried about IE, I know that browser has some issues in itself. Anyway, would anyone on here have an idea to resolve this issue, if I can? Or even, what could be causing this issue?

Here is my website to see for yourselves. www.voelkerdesigner.com

Cheers!

Comment: You might wanna include some of your code, not just posting a link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the opposite for me your entire site works in firefox for me but not in chrome, looking through your code, its being caused by your naming conventions. Namely **#advertise**

I use the adguard extension in chrome and below is the css it plugs into my html pages to hide ads, so im guessing your using an adblocker in firefox

```
#adsense_top, #adsensewide, #adspace, #adspace_top, #adspot-300x250-pos-1, #adspot-300x250-pos-2, #adswidget1-quick-adsense, #adswidget2-quick-adsense, #adtext, #adtop, #adv-masthead, #adv-top, #advert1, #advert2, #advertbox3, #advertise, #advertisement1, #advertisetop, #advertising-container, #advertising_wrapper {
display: none!important;
}
```

Comment: Yep, disabled Ad Blocker, was able to see the content. Confirmed.

Comment: Good catch with the adblock

Comment: EUREKA! It was the ad blocker! Yes, I did have it running on that page. That's interesting the ad-blocker was affecting that. It was driving me crazy why it wasn't working! THANK YOU! I really appreciate it.

Comment: something as simple as naming content/variables/code as popup/advert/hotlink and so on can trigger certain blockers.. Its a tricky subject as do you develop without a blocker or with one to see if they dislike site content... I guess allow full access to your site during dev and then enable the blocker again and see what it picks up on.. does it have a log at all? might be handy

Answer (score 0):

Might as well post a random answer on this... As i wont visit posted links by new users.. i'm just gonna guess that your background image might not be 100%...

In general i use background-image instead of background.. Short hand can be a little pain and breaks in some browsers if not perfect.

so i would compare against the following example

```
background-image:url('images/mybg.jpg');
background-image:url('http://somesite.com/images/mybg.jpg');
```

Basically alot of people do not use the url and just go straight for a file name or dont quote it.. And have seen that be the problem in the past, so do use the url('') method.

Otherwise if it still fails to work and you know the image is absolute, you would then have some other css that is either over riding your elements background or is preventing it from loading.

Another trick is using your console / inspect element to manually inject the background-image and see if that works... So once the page has loaded in chrome, inspect the element as normal.. And double click on your css property listing as you can add your own styles this way and if it fails, then its not the markup but something else.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I understand not looking at my website since I'm a new user. No worries. But I think the issue has been resolved because my Ad-Blocker was affecting the page.

Comment: Saw the post by user3365721, glad he caught that as something like can keep people wondering for days why something is not working.