# img not showing up inside div

Tags: html, css, image, iframe

Here's my code

```
               <div class="table">
                    <div class="tr">
                        <div class="td">
                            <h1 class="logo-fill">
                                <a href="#" title="Logo">
                                    <img alt="logo" src="./images/logo.png" />
                                </a>
                            </h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="td">
                            <a href="#" title="AdSpace">
                                <img alt="adspace" src="./images/adspace.png" />
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

For some reason, the second image (adspace.png) is not displaying at all. If I remove the entire img tag and replace it with text, the text is displayed. Alternativly if I change the img tag to:

```
<iframe src="https://clients.ragezone.com/out.php/display/show_custom?id=48" scrolling="no" style="padding: 0px; overflow: hidden;" width="468px" height="60px" frameborder="no"></iframe>
```

Apparently that works as well. adspace.png is simply a 468px x 60px green box.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28933906 It’s because of AdBlock Plus. Would this be a duplicate?

Comment: check the browser dev tools. do you see errors there?

Comment: Try renaming the adspace.png file to something different.

Comment: Wow, totally didn't think of the fact that I'm developing using tools like those...It's funny 'cause it shows no errors and no blocks though. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

My money would be on the fact that you have an **adblocker** in your browser. Try changing class names and img name. 
Adblocker plugins search for certain keywords in the code and block the page elements based on that.

Answer (score 0):

In your image source path I saw one [dot] miss placed that may be a one problem.

This is your code

```
<img alt="adspace" src="./images/adspace.png" />
```

And try with this one

```
<img alt="adspace" src="../images/adspace.png" />
```

And other problem is your image name I also faced to this issue your image name is adspace.png and you added alt="adspace" and wrap it with link tag having the title with Adspace so the reason is some of plugins in your browser block all the images and divs starting with "ads / ad" this is called adblock plugins.

So you can easily change your img name and change everything starting with "ad" then you can find some useful fixing. Other way is you can remove the adblock plugins from your browser.

**And please check your network too some networks admin can block ads too.**